# zsh: permission denied: webstorm - On Attempting to Create Shell Script That Launches WebStorm

Tags: macos, zsh, webstorm

I am following the documentation on creating a Shell script that launches the WebStorm application for a given file folder as described on [WebStorm Help page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/working-with-the-ide-features-from-command-line.html#toolbox). I am currently using an M1 Pro Macbook (2022) that I just got today and has little else installed beyond Homebrew, VSCode, WebStorm, and PyCharm.

Following the example in the docs, I created a file called `webstorm` (without any extension) in `usr/local/bin` and added the following code to it:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

open -na "WebStorm.app" --args "$@"
```

After starting up a new terminal, and running `webstorm .`, I get the following error in my terminal:

```bash
zsh: permission denied: webstorm
```

I have:

1. Changed `sh` to `zsh` as my default shell is `zsh`, and that made no difference.
2. Checked my permissions for both `usr/local/bin` and `usr/local/bin/webstorm` to ensure that I have the correct permissions to execute files from here. When right clicking on the `webstorm` file and clicking "Get Info", I can see that I currently have read and write permissions.
3. Restarted my computer

To add to my confusion, I have used the same script in the same location on my work Macbook, and it has worked without issues.

Any help on this would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Do you also have **execute** permission on `/usr/local/bin/webstorm`? The problem is not in your script: Your script simply starts the **app** _WebStorm_. My guess is that WebStorm.app during initialization wants to run the executable `webstorm`, and at this point the error occurs. I don't know webstorm, but what happens if you run `/usr/local/bin/webstorm` from your command line?

Comment: Why is this tagged _javascript_? I don't see any JavaScript in your question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Checked my permissions for both usr/local/bin and usr/local/bin/webstorm to ensure that I have the correct permissions to execute files from here. When right clicking on the webstorm file and clicking "Get Info", I can see that I currently have read and write permissions.

Do you have the "**execute**" permission?

Try:

```bash
$ chmod +x /usr/local/bin/webstorm
```